# Employees can be assigned three tasks if and only if $|N(A)| \geq 3|A|$ for all $A \subseteq E$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

$E = \{e_1, e_2,\ldots, e_m\}$ is the set of employees of your company. These employees are to be given tasks from the task list $J = \{j_1, j_2,\ldots, j_n\}$. Each employee is qualified for some of the tasks, and we want to assign each employee to three tasks. Each task will get one or zero employees.

If $A \subseteq E$ is a collection of the employees, then $N(A)\subseteq J$ will denote the collection of all the tasks that can be performed by some member of $A$ (i.e., the union of the lists of the members of $A$).
Prove that we can accomplish our assignment if and only if
$|N(A)| \geq 3|A|$ for all $A \subseteq E$.

Comment: Both $E$ and $J$ are indexed up to $m$, which indicates that the sets have the same size. I don't think that's supposed to be the case. Should it be, say, $j_n$ instead?

Comment: It might be of help to think of the bigraph with vertex sets $E$ and $J$ and "Employee $e_m$ is given job $j_n$ is represented by edge $e_mj_n$ in the mentioned bigraph. Then, we need to show that $$d(j_n)\leq 1~\land~d(e_m)=3~\forall~m,n\iff |N(A)|\geq 3|A|$$ where $d(v)$ denotes the degree of a vertex $v$ and $N(v)$ denotes the neighbourhood of a vertex $v$ and $N(A):=\bigcup\limits_{v\in A}N(v)$

Comment: If $m\gt0$ the condition $|N(A)|\ge3|A|$ fails for $A=E$ because $3|A|=3m$ while $|N(A)|\le m.$

Comment: The only-if side is easy enough. You might even say obvious, but it still needs to be stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- If you were to consider a graph $G'$ in which each employee-vertex has been copied two more times (i.e., each employee vertex happens in three copies), then your theorem is a version of [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).
- If you want to prove it directly, consider two cases:

  1. There exist a proper subset $A$ with $|N(A)| = 3|A|$.
  2. For all proper subsets we have $|N(A)| > 3|A|$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Mostly rewording your question, but can't think of any more info to give without giving the answer away...

$N(A)$ is the set of all tasks that we can choose from when assigning tasks to employees in the set $A$. Each employee in $A$ must be assigned to 3 tasks, and each task can be assigned to at most on employee...